# Jenkins - publish version number for each build

Tags: jenkins, reporting, jenkins-plugins

We are testing an embedded system which is a Linux image with several components in it. When a new image is released, it gets a version, e.g. Image 1.0.1 and in it each component in it has its own version. e.g. component1-2.0.3, component2-4.1.22 etc. Image generation is done externally (I don't know how).

We are automating testing of our system, so now our testing looks like this:

- Every night, download the newest image
- For each component, execute tests on the image.
  This currently works ok.

The end goal of Jenkins testing would be generation of reports for each image version. E.g.

```
Image 1.0.1
Testing results
Component1-2.0.3, passing 100, failing 20, etc.
Component2-4.1.22, passing 34, failing 3, etc.
```

I don't know how to do this automatically, so please help.
I need information about:

- When the build job starts, in the log I can see the version of the component and version of the image on which the test was executed. How to publish these informations, so next to the each build, on the summary page, I can see version of the component and version of the image on which the build was executed.
- How to create a final reports as given above from the informations I have in Jenkins?

Any experiences, plugins and information are welcome.

Comment: So, each job is testing a different image, is that right? Is `Image 1.0.1` part of the job name? Also, how are your tests launched?

Comment: No, each job tests a different component. I load image to the dedicate place on hard drive, and tests are performed on this image.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the text finder plugin to search for a specific text in the build log - you can user regular expression for that.
Then you can echo the result to a file that will include all the components and add it to the build summary

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you can see the versions in the log so just use a regular expression in an email body:

```
Component1 Version: ${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex="^Component1-", showTruncatedLines=false, substText=""}
Component2 Version: ${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex="^Component2-", showTruncatedLines=false, substText=""}
```

BUILD_LOG_REGEX uses following regular expression:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to match needed information in the build log and set build description with [Groovy Postbuild Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin):

```java
image = manager.getLogMatcher(/Image ([\d.]+).*/).group(1)
comp1 = manager.getLogMatcher(/Component1-([\d.]+).*/).group(1)
comp2 = manager.getLogMatcher(/Component2-([\d.]+).*/).group(1)

manager.build.description = "<b>Image:</b> ${image} <b>Comp1:</b> ${comp1} <b>Comp2:</b> ${comp2}"
```

As a result you will have versions of your components for each build description:

[image]